# Rot 13 Minimal Version Java

Tags: java, encryption, rot13

I tried to implement Rot13 and to make it as minimal as possible, this are my results so far:

```
    if ( (c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z') ) 
        c=((c-'A'+13)%26)+'A';

    if ( (c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z') )
        c=((c-'a'+13)%26)+'a';

    return c;
```

I showed this to my Prof and he said it would be possible in two lines. I don't know how i could shrink this code further and not generating wrong output.

Thanks for your help

EDIT: if nothing changed (outer range ascii) it should only return c. Maybe the solution is the second answer + return line c in case nothing returned.

Comment: Probably something for codegolf.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Your professor shouldn't encourage making your code as terse as possible. Fewer lines does not always mean better code. In many cases it's the opposite.

Comment: I can see a fair number of  ways to make it a one-liner or two-liner, but I can't guess which one he's thinking of or if he's got something else in mind. The ?: operator, assignment in mid-expression, taking advantage of the fact that uppercase vs. lowercase is a single bit difference...

I would HOPE that what he wants is not the minimum number of lines, but the most efficient code (minimum number of / simplest operations).

Comment: i think mtk's option will do it, if the prof doesn't specify, the question anymore it will do. thanks to all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly more correct than Sibbo's answer. This returns c as is if it falls in neither range. and in 1 line.

```
return ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) ? ((c-'A'+13)%26)+'A'
                                 :((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z') ? ((c-'a'+13)%26)+'a'
                                                                  : c);
```

Comment: Good, except just return instead of assign to c again

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to update `c`; just return:

```
if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) {
    return ((c - 'A' + 13) % 26) + 'A';
}

if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) {
    return ((c - 'a' + 13) % 26) + 'a';
}
```

I also made the code more readable.

This could easily be made into two lines:

```
if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) return ((c - 'A' + 13) % 26) + 'A';
if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) return ((c - 'a' + 13) % 26) + 'a';
```

Or one:

```
if ((c >= 'A') && (c <= 'Z')) return ((c - 'A' + 13) % 26) + 'A'; if ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) return ((c - 'a' + 13) % 26) + 'a';
```

But of course, that is much less readable, and not a good idea.

Comment: @AmirAfghani Okay, if you insist... :P

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow, oh, its imperative ... ;)

Comment: +1. I can write my whole project in one line now , by seeing your last line of code :P

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow: I know you are a code golfer :) Take a look at my code. I think it is awesome :)

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Woah, that's great :P Still Python 2 wins on this one: `'string'.encode('rot13')` :P

Answer (score 3):

One line:

```
return (c < 'a') ? ((c - 'A' + 13) % 26) + 'A' : ((c - 'a' + 13) % 26) + 'a';
```

This simply makes use of the fact that lower case letters come after upper case letters in ASCII and UTF-8. Of course, it doesn't verify the input in any way.

Comment: And that if you put this in production code, your boss will take pleasure in crucifying you.

Comment: This is..not correct? As it applies calculations even if c is not between A and Z or a and z

Comment: Yes, that's true. It assumes that c is in the correct range, as stated in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is a little trick using the ASCII table. Upper and lower case chars only differ one bit. So you could handle them at once. Take a look at this:

```
A = 0100 0001     M = 0100 1101
a = 0110 0001     m = 0110 1101
```

So, I think this should work:

```
if (Character.isLetter(c))
   return (char) ((((c & 0b01011111) - 'A' + 13) % 26 + 'A') | (c & 0b00100000));
return c;
```

**Explanation:**

1. `c & 0b01011111` turns the char into an uppercase.
2. `- 'A' + 13` converts to an 0-based int and applies the offset.
3. `% 26 + 'A'` Take the modulo and make it back a char.
4. `(c & 0b00100000)` takes the bit that indicates wether the char was lower case or not.
5. `|` Add that bit back to the result to make it lowercase if it was.

You could use the conditional operator here to make it a one-liner:

```
return Character.isLetter(c) ? (char) ((((c & 0b01011111) - 'A' + 13) % 26 + 'A') | (c & 0b00100000)) : c;
```

After replacing the binary and char literals by decimal int literals, you get:

```
return Character.isLetter(c) ? (char) ((((c & 95) - 52) % 26 + 65) | (c & 32)) : c;
```

Eliminating spaces and some extra brackets gives: (**65 chars**)

```
return Character.isLetter(c)?(char)((((c&95)-52)%26+65)|c&32):c;
```

Which is a win, IMHO, if it comes to code golfing. This is of course not readable.

---

**Demo:** Yep, confirmed. It works: http://ideone.com/l6xYy6

Excerpt from the output:

```
= -> =
> -> >
? -> ?
@ -> @
A -> N
B -> O
C -> P
D -> Q
```

And a bit further:

```
W -> J
X -> K
Y -> L
Z -> M
[ -> [
\ -> \
] -> ]
^ -> ^
_ -> _
` -> `
a -> n
b -> o
c -> p
d -> q
```

Comment: I _think_ Character.isLetter is locale dependent, so it may return true for non ascii letters.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: I know. But that isn't really a problem here? Aren't we just talking about ASCII?

Comment: I'm guessing it's not a problem in this case, but since it takes/returns int I thought I'd point it out since future readers may accidentally try to use it for other ranges :)

Answer (score 1):

Even shorter and (perhaps) still easier to read is

```
char a = c < 'a' ? 'A' : 'a';
return (c - a + 13) % 26 + a;
```

Note that this solution, like some of the previous answers, doesn't check the input. Moreover, in Java this code returns an int, not a char, so a cast would be necessary if the method in which it is included returns a char.

As already mentioned, I also like to stress that shortest is not necessarily best. Write readable code.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if we're going for short over readable;

```java
return (c&~32) >= 'A' && (c&~32) <= 'Z' ? ((c&31) + 12) % 26 + (c&~31) + 1 : c;
```

Comment: @StefanSprenger I'd argue that none of the answers make the intent of the code very clear. You can decode them as rot13 with some work, but none is of the type where an unknowing programmer reads the code and immediately thinks "ah, rot13" :)

Comment: @JoachimIsakkson: Agree :)